# Access MS Graph data with AAD clients AND Microsoft clients like outlook.com via Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, adal, azure-ad-msal

I can access MS graph in a web api with AAD setting up an AAD application registration etcetera.

I can create an application on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and access graph from the javascript front end

I can't log in both (I assume I have to create two different login workflows?)

Is it possible to log in and pass credentials (JWT or whatever) to a c# web api and access graph for AAD and accounts like outlook.com?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't log in both (I assume I have to create two different login
>   workflows?)
>
> Is it possible to log in and pass credentials (JWT or whatever) to a
>   c# web api and access graph for AAD and accounts like outlook.com?

For the application created in AAD, you could not log in the application with the outlook.com, the AAD registered applications belong to `v1.0 endpoint`, you could only sign in with work and school accounts.

The application registered on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ belongs to `v2.0 endpoint`, it allows work and school accounts from Azure AD and personal accounts (MSA) (hotmail.com, outlook.com, msn.com) to sign in.

For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#who-can-sign-in).

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: If the answer is useful for you, please help mark it, thanks!